# Cannot expand $ERTS_LIB_DIR in bootfile

Tags: erlang, rebar, relx

I created a release using rebar3 but I have issues running/booting the app on my remote server.

When i run the following command:

```
$> /home/app/releases/0.0.1# erl -boot start
```

I get the following error:

```
{"init terminating in do_boot",'cannot expand $ERTS_LIB_DIR in bootfile'}
init terminating in do_boot (cannot expand $ERTS_LIB_DIR in bootfile)

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you creating a release? If you do something like `rebar3 as prod tar`, you'll get a .tar.gz that can be expanded on the server, with `bin/APP` used to start/stop/attach.

If you do something like `rebar3 release`, it'll build into `_build`, with the start/stop script being in `_build/default/rel/APP/bin/APP`.

Comment: Created release with rebar3 as prod tar. Isn't it possible to start the app using erl -boot start?

Comment: Not sure, but why not just use the generated script in the bin/ dir?