# Rebar3 release does not run and crash with cannot expand $ERTS_LIB_DIR in bootfile

Tags: erlang, rebar3

> Erlang Version = Erlang/OTP 19

I have created a new erlang application using rebar3
Here are the steps:

```
rebar3 new app myapp
rebar3 compile
rebar3 new release myrel
cd myrel
rebar3 release
cd myrel/myapp/_build/default/rel/myapp/bin
./myapp start
```

I get the following error:

> init terminating in do_boot (cannot expand $ERTS_LIB_DIR in bootfile)
>   Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done

Can someone please check what I am missing here?
Thanks.

Comment: Anything on this guys? I am not sure how to resolve this

Comment: This seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41145677/cannot-expand-erts-lib-dir-in-bootfile

Comment: This also seems like the same error in a different context: https://github.com/bitwalker/distillery/issues/235

Comment: Anyway this is because it is a relx issue. And the team is looking into it. It works from outside the bin directory. This is also raised in rebar issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot expand $ERTS\_LIB\_DIR in bootfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41145677/cannot-expand-erts-lib-dir-in-bootfile)

Comment: It's not clear what you want to accomplish; don't do a release, do: rebar3 compile and  then rebar3 tar -d false -i true for a standalone package.

Answer (score 0):

If you do something like `rebar3 as prod tar` you should get a `.tar.gz` file that can be expanded on the server, with `bin/myapp` used to start/stop/attach. If you do something like `rebar3 release`, it'll build into `_build/`, with the start/stop script being in `_build/default/rel/myapp/bin/myapp`. Why are you using `rebar3 new release myrel`?